# Display 1 value at a time from json file

Tags: reactjs

Don't have much experience with react and i'm blocked at getting only one value from a json file and display it. 
To be more specific, i have this json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "digit": "12345"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "digit": "43215"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "digit": "34565"
  }
]
```

and what i want is to display a single value for the card, and when i refresh the page to update the value with the next one and so on.

```
class randomCard extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      card: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('.card-code.json', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          card: data,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-wrapper">
        <div>
          {this.state.card.map(codes => (
            <span className="card-item">{codes.digit}</span>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

right now i'm getting 123454321534565

any ideas on how i can do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you refresh the page whole page is refreshed so you will again so the default value what you want ? if you want to show only one value then you can do simply  <span className="card-item">{this.state.card[0].digit}</span>

Comment: Don't put `card.digit` it should be `codes.digit`, because you are mapping the variable card from your state.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-wrapper">
        <div>
          {this.state.card.map((codes,index) => (
            <span className="card-item" key={index}>{codes.digit}</span>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter to the state and every time you refresh you show the next card item until you get the counter == card.length.

Comment: OP's requirement is quite different, he has just a typo otherwise he is getting correct value's.